# Why can't the pdf file created by gage (a R packge) be opened

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying to use Gage package implemented in R to analyze my RNA-seq data. I followed the tutorial and got my data.kegg.p file and  I used the following script to generate the heatmap for the top gene set

```
for (gs in rownames(data.kegg.p$greater)[1]) {
  outname = gsub(" |:|/", "_", substr(gs, 10, 100))
  geneData(genes = kegg.gs[[gs]], exprs = essData, ref = 1,
  samp = 2, outname = outname, txt = T, heatmap = T,
  Colv = F, Rowv = F, dendrogram = "none", limit = 3, scatterplot = T)
  }
```

I did get a pdf file named "NOD-like_receptor_signaling_pathway.geneData.heatmap.pdf", but when I open this file with acrobat reader or photoshop, it gives the error information that this file has been disrupted and cannot be recovered. Could anyone help check this file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrsml6n1pbrztnm/NOD-like_receptor_signaling_pathway.geneData.heatmap.pdf?dl=0) to see whether it is really disrupted and is it possible to find a way to recover it?

I also attached the R workspace file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/6n5m9x5hyk38ff1/A549.RData?dl=0). The object "a4" is the data with the format ready for gage analysis. It contains the data of the reference sample (nc) the treated sample (a549). It can be accepted by gage for analysis but generate the heatmap pdf file which cannot be opened (above). Would you mind helping me check whether these data can be properly used to generated the correct gage result?

Best regards.

Comment: Please don't use dropbox or other cloud services to share data. Those links tend to break over time and represent security risks, thus SO policy is to include everything to reproduce the problem within the question itself. For the `r` tag the description specifies the use of `dput()` to share data.

Comment: Where can I find the instructions of how to use dput() to share data?

Comment: You just type `dput()` around the data object that you want to share and then copy and paste the output. For example `dput(data.kegg.p)`.

Comment: In base R, pdfs usually fail to open when the `pdf` function is not closed with `dev.off`. Doesn't your plotting function require something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into a similar problem myself. Not 100% sure but I think this problem occurs when there is no heatmap to plot. In my case, I was doing `as.group` comparison with `ref` and `sample` selections. I think the software treats this circumstance as a sample n of 1 and can't really show a differential heatmap. When I tried using `1ongroup` setting, I was able to visualize the pdf file.